# Directional derivative chain rule for nonsmooth function

Tags: calculus

For function $f(x)$ on $\mathbb{R}$, the directional derivative $f'(x; y)$ on direction $y$ is defined by $f'(x;y)=\lim_{t\to 0+}\frac{f(x+ty)-f(x)}{t}$. If $f$ is differentiable, then $f'(x;y)=yf'(x)$. Now, if $f'_+(x)$ is the right-side derivative at $x$ (not differentiable at $x$, for instance $f(x)=|x|$ at $x=0$), is that true $f'(x;y)=yf_+'(x)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x)=-x$ for $x <0$ and $0$ for $x \geq 0$. Then $f'_{+}(0)=0$. take $y=-1$. Then $\frac {f(0+ty)-f(0)} {t}=\frac {-ty} t \to 1$ as $t \to 0+$ whereas $yf'_{+}(0)=0$.

Comment: Suppose $f(x)$ is additionally symmetric and $f'_+(x) > 0$. Does the assertion hold?